# Angular Changing filter based on select value and text input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular so I think this is a basic concept that I'm just missing some step on. I want to have a search that does basic angular filtering, but I want to have a separate select that chooses what the text input searches on. Currently it looks like this:

Search inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-users" ng-model="userQuery">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select ng-model="searchOn" ng-change="setSearchOn(searchOn)">
            <option value="CustomerId" selected>CustomerId</option>
            <option value="Username">Username</option>
        </select>
      </span>
```

Function:

```
$scope.setSearchOn = function(searchOnIn){
            console.log("setting searchOn to "+searchOnIn);
            $scope.searchOn = searchOnIn;
        }
```

Repeater:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userQuery.searchOn">
```

I feel like i shouldn't even need the function, shouldn't i be able to data-bind the value of the select to the filter on the repeater? I couldn't get that to work either. Help would be appreciated. Angular is awesome, but the beginning learning the way it works is a little rough :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, we want to pick the property which we search on with the dropdown, and then search that property for value on the userQuery input.

One way to accomplish that is to (re)build an object to filter with when either `userQuery` or `searchOn` alters.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    /* some test data */
    $scope.users = [{CustomerId : 1, Username : 'Pete'},
                   {CustomerId : 2, Username : 'John'},
                   {CustomerId : 3, Username : 'Claus'}]

    $scope.setSearchFilter = function()
    {
        $scope.searchFilter = {};
        $scope.searchFilter[$scope.searchOn] = $scope.userQuery;
    }
})
```

In the html, I've set an `ng-change` on both the `userQuery` and `searchOn` to update the search filter.

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-users" ng-model="userQuery" ng-change="setSearchFilter()" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select ng-model="searchOn" ng-change="setSearchFilter()">
            <option value="CustomerId" selected>CustomerId</option>
            <option value="Username">Username</option>
        </select>
      </span>

      <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchFilter">
          {{user.CustomerId}} -- {{user.Username}}
      </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwdx7/1/

Comment: Thanks for responding! When I do this as you described I keep getting userQuery not defined because it is just a model in the html file. I tried adding a $scope.userQuery, but am running into similar issues.

If I understand what you're doing the filter:searchFilter is becoming filter:userQuery[CustomerId] which is pretty much what I want, but I don't understand how the ng model would become a variable and then inject into the filter.

Comment: Ah, I missed that `userQuery` is the model for an input.  But then I have to ask, what do you expect `userQuery[CustomerId]` to be? Because `$scope.userQuery` is some text value, it won't have a CustomerId property. I'll try to throw a simpe jsfiddle together that does something I think makes sense.

Comment: I guess I am trying to get the model for `userQuery` to dynamically change based on the select. If I was going to search for CustomerId the userQuery ng-model would be `userQuery.CustomerId` right? so I want to bind searchOn to userQuery. I thought I could do `userQuery.searchOn` and it would bind them but I was wrong.

Comment: As I move forward this is going to be a common gap in my understanding. I just added `limitTo:100` to the repeater to show the first 100 results only, but i should be able to click something to change that and inject how many results to show like `limitTo:numRecords` ?

Comment: Here is the jQuery equivalent that works, but I know I shouldn't be using jQuery here, there's gotta be an eloquent angular version:

`$("#search-on").change(function(){
   var searchOn = jQuery(this).val();
   if(searchOn != ""){
    $("#search-users").attr("ng-model","userQuery."+jQuery(this).val());
   } else {
    $("#search-users").attr("ng-model","userQuery");
   }
  });`

Comment: Yeah, I think so. As long as `numRecords` is a `$scope` property (so e.g. bound via `ng-model` to an input). This filtering business is (also) proving a bit more difficult than I expected, and it's late, so I'll have a further look tomorrow. But I did make a basic fiddle if anyone else wants to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/nwdx7/

Comment: But when I do `userQuery.searchOn` and then change to CustomerId `searchOn` in the scope should be CustomerId but then searches fail, it shows no results

Comment: @PixMach I've edited my answer to a tested&working example. Though I'll have to think a bit more on whether it can be done without relying on `ng-change` (or improved in other ways. For example, there's the option of creating a custom filter).